# Light-independent shader in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders

Is there a way to create a light-independent shader in cycles? The purpose is to create "green screens" to separate a 3d image into depth layers. The output will be a single rgb value (e.g. 0R, 1.0G, 0B) that can be color-selected and set to transparent in Photoshop or GIMP.

The reason to do this instead of using a depth layer to filter a single rendering pass is so that the foreground can be omitted from background renders in a parallax video.

Note: yes, all visibility in the object is off except for the camera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the transparent background for free. Just enable *Transparent* under *Render > Film*.

[image]

In case there really is no way around the green screen, use an emission shader for your plate, set its color to green and disable all *Ray Visibility* options except *Camera Visibility*.

[image]

Comment: Excellent, thanks!  Your first option is the best; had to use your second option since background elements affect the lighting for the foreground elements.